# Advanced Search Options Syntax: Multiple Tags, And Vs. Or

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, search

I am hitting a tag for unanswered, open questions using

```
[myTag]closed:0 answers:0
```

But I wanted to add another tag to the search. Unfortunately just doing:

```
[myTag][myOtherTag]closed:0 answers:0
```

Returns only questions with *both* tags. I was going for *either* tag. I can't seem to find the syntax.

Is this implemented yet? (And if not can it be?)

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C%23%20OR%20python

Comment: Yes, but how do you also get the closed:0 and answers:0 part in there?

Answer (score 2):

Well since the original answer someone got drunk and gave me source code access, so how about we allow `OR` tags?

Your search can now be performed like this: `[myTag] or [myOtherTag]closed:0 answers:0`, this would return results containing either tag.  Here are a few more examples:

- `[myTag] or [myTag2] or [myTag3] closed:0 answers:0` - any of the 3 tags
- `[myTag] or [myTag2] [myTag3] closed:0 answers:0` - either of the first 2 **and** the 3rd tag
- `[myTag] or [myTag2] [myTag3] or [myTag4] closed:0 answers:0` - either of the first 2 **and** either of the last 2 `(A || B) && (C || D)`

---

*Original:* Just throwing this option out there, certain tags could be reserved for this purposed: e.g. `[closed]`, `[unanswered]`, `[deleted]`, `[protected]`, etc. (Maybe these are *already* reserved?).  The search could handle these appropriately on the back-end as special filters.

I'm not sure that this would be the best approach, but it would be a way to keep the syntax simpler overall.

Alternatively, you could allow counts to be put in, e.g. `[answers:1]`, in this case `[unanswered]` would be a simple alias for `[answers:0]`, allowing more flexibility overall...maybe this is over-complicating things though, I'm not sure how many would use this feature...

Comment: This wouldn't help. The problem is being able to specify either an `AND` or `OR` operator on the tags (right now it's always `AND`) while still being able to use the other `closed` and `answers` filters.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Look at perbert's answer, you can already do `OR`, though not via the search box.

Comment: Yes, but as soon as you start adding the search options (like `answers:1`), the URL changes completely and `OR` is unsupported.

Comment: @Jon: Do you mean something like this?: `([c#] OR [.net]) AND [answers:1]`  With nested sets of operators?  My thoughts would be these special tags are always conditions, only the tags themselves would be `OR`, so these tags directly translate to an additional `where...` clause, where as your tag search would be one `where` that's an `OR` inside...not sure if I'm explaining that well, hope I am.

Comment: Right, the special conditions are always `AND`'d together (which makes sense), but what I'm saying is that the `OR` operator for the tags is currently not supported when adding the special conditions to the search.

Answer (score 0):

I support this request for tag search with OR combined with other options.
Meanwhile, I use a custom  [SE filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters) and choose the "no answers" tab. This emulates OR on tags, but it doesn't allow other options such as `closed:0`, etc.