# How can I use advanced search parameters while ORing tags?

Tags: support, search

I want to use advanced parameters such as `votes:2 is:question` while ORing tags `[javascript] [or] [php]`

I can't get this to work:

```
[javascript] [or] [php] votes:2 is:question
```

Someone else had the [same problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33099/advanced-search-options-syntax-multiple-tags-and-vs-or#comment92896_41681), but it seems he did not cared enough to open a question (at least not under the [search](/questions/tagged/search)<sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsearch%5D%20user:13295%20is:question)</sup> or [advanced-search](/questions/tagged/advanced-search) <sup>[2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Badvanced-search%5D%20user:13295%20is:question)</sup> tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a plain `or` between 2 or more tags, like this:
`[javascript] or [php] votes:2 is:question`

[You can test it out here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20or%20%5Bphp%5D%20votes:2%20is:question).