# Better support for search by both intersection and union of multiple tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, filtering

Search supports filtering by tags intersection e.g., [[python] [timezone]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+timezone). It finds posts that have both tags. See
[Filtering questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17003/137096).

Search supports filtering by tags union e.g., [[datetime] or [timezone]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime+or+timezone). It find posts that have either of the tags. See [Advanced Search Options Syntax: Multiple Tags, And Vs. Or](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33099/137096).

It is possible to do both. For example, to find posts that have `[python]` tag and have either `[datetime]` or `[timezone]` tags: [[python] [datetime] [or] [timezone] [python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%20datetime%20or%20timezone%20python). Note: It is necessary to repeat `[python]` and it is necessary to use brackets around `OR`.  See [Search for questions tagged [A] and also (tagged [B] or [C])](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137265/137096).

Could we write it as `[python] ([datetime] or [timezone])` instead?

[searching using both “and” and “or” (sum-of-products or product-of-sums)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176155/137096) demonstrates that [`[python] ([datetime] or [timezone]) is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bpython%5d%20(%5bdatetime%5d%20or%20%5btimezone%5d)%20is%3aquestion) already works: it shows relevant question despite incorrect "tagged with" on the right.

Query on data stackexchange: [Find [A] ([B] or [C])](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194481/find-a-b-or-c).

Related: [How do active answerers find questions to answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254592/4279)

Comment: Just BTW, I once raised this in a comment on some other answer, and a dev said the tag search backend could handle parens, but the frontend had trouble displaying them.