# Custom question lists December status update

Tags: discussion, question-lists, custom-question-lists

> **Previous posts:**
>
> - [Custom question lists: finding questions you can answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer)
> - [Custom question lists is available for testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/custom-question-lists-is-available-for-testing)
> - [Custom question lists October status update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317675/custom-question-lists-october-status-update)

Nothing new has shipped. But we're close.

### Where are things with Phase 2?

Phase 2, the ability to save Custom Question Lists (CQLs), is almost ready to ship. It got stalled, a lot. Part of that was that I ended up spending more time on Winter Bash hat triggers than I thought, part of that was more significant changes than I was expecting, and part of that was the turnaround time on reviews and re-reviews. Excuses, I know.

As it stands right now, the code is out of review *but* the architecture team needs to ship its Phase 3 changes for [TagEngine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296066/what-is-the-tag-engine-server-implementation-in-stack-overflow/296329#296329) alongside the Phase 2 changes for the web, and they don't want to ship a big architectural changes to performance-critical code right before all the architects go on vacation. So, January.

### Where are things with Phase 3?

As mentioned above, the biggest hurdles for Phase 3, navigation and new content indicators, have are almost resolved. I'm expecting the UI work will be pretty straightforward, just needing to be optimized. But given the delays in Phase 2, I'm not going to publicly suggest any rollout date.

Comment: I was not sure whether to upvote or downvote because there will be no CQLs as christmas gift but I upvoted because it's great that you write these posts.

Comment: @MEE I'd rather have it properly validated and supportable in January than shipped now and if something goes wrong, tough luck.

Comment: @MonicaCellio yeah I know but it would have been a great gift :(

Comment: @MEE my ideal scenario would for 5 people to upvote it and another 5 to downvote it. Then again, you could not and then no one would get a Christmas gift. 

Comment: @BrianNickel sorry for my inpatience but the last update was years ago (ok one). Is there anything new?

Comment: @MEE Just waiting for everyone to be on deck to ship it.  The architect involved is out this week and we have a company-wide thing happening next week, so we'll finalize the shipping plan the week after that.

Comment: @BrianNickel ok. You know last time you told me “a few weeks” it became “next year” :D but I will still trust you that you do the right thing.

Comment: @MEE Yeah, sorry, there's been a lot more starting and stopping on this than I was expecting.  On the surface a lot of what we're doing is superficial, but it's running up against and integrating with some of the most performance critical stuff we have.

Comment: @BrianNickel yeah it would be bad if you accidentally ddosed Stack Overflow :P. I also wanted to say thank you for working on this probably amazing feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom question lists January status update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323202/custom-question-lists-january-status-update)