# Custom question lists January status update

Tags: discussion, question-lists, custom-question-lists

> **Previous posts:**
>
> - [Custom question lists: finding questions you can answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer)
> - [Custom question lists is available for testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/custom-question-lists-is-available-for-testing)
> - [Custom question lists October status update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317675/custom-question-lists-october-status-update)
> - [Custom question lists December status update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320730/custom-question-lists-december-status-update)

After a lackluster December update, I'm happy to report that Custom Question Lists Phase 2 (saving) has shipped!

### What's shipped?

If you are participating in the Custom Question List alpha (by [checking a box on your profile and waiting](/users/preferences/current)), you'll see a new section in the "More" dropdown:

[image: Screenshot showing "Custom Views" in the "More" menu]

Clicking the + button launch a dialog with the same options as the Filter and Sort options giving you the ability to save the view.

[image: Screenshot of custom view dialog]

Once configured and saved, the view will be quickly accessible and configurable from the "More" menu:

[image: Screenshot of the "More" menu with two saved question lists]

Please give it a try.  If you have any questions, bugs, or feedback, you can reply to this post directly or add a new question with the [custom-question-lists](/questions/tagged/custom-question-lists) tag.

### What's next?

Phase 3 of this project is to add more utility to these saved lists, adding them to the main left navigation and adding indicators for new content.

We've already made significant progress on this front, our production Tag Server is already set up to send back content notifications and I have a version of the web app running locally.  It still needs to go through architecture review, get a design treatment, and get a healthy dose of performance testing and other scrutiny, but the end is near.

Comment: Are the "Filter" and "Sort" dropdowns on the right side supposed to be independent of the custom question list? When I create a custom view and then change the filter or sort setting, it creates a new "unsaved" custom view. I assumed it would just apply the sort or filter to my existing view.

Comment: @KodosJohnson They're independent of the question list. Changing them moves you to a new list with those settings.  Can you add your feedback as an answer and I'll raise it to our designers to look at the UX?

Comment: Also, enabling this doesn't mean you necessarily *have* to answer more questions, right?

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

OoOoh new stuff! Unfortunately, I've had it for five minutes and broke it a little.

I added [regex], then I tried to add [regex*] as a wildcard match (pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> to add it) and it didn't work, instead adding a second regex tag, creating a view like this:

> [image]

The other nav (RIP) let me use wildcards, so this one should too.

Comment: Now you have two problems.

Comment: This is fixed.  There were just some UI rules that needed tweaking.  That said, [tag:regex] is the only tag to match `/regex*/` so in a sense was matching a wildcard.

Comment: @BrianNickel It’s on Stack Overflow so it matches a number of tags.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Are the "Filter" and "Sort" dropdowns on the right side supposed to be independent of the custom question list? When I create a custom view and then change the filter or sort setting, it creates a new "unsaved" custom view. I assumed it would just apply the sort or filter to my existing view.

Comment: We redid the UI in way that _should_ address this problem.  Those buttons are gone, replaced with a more unified UI.

Answer (score 5):

[plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is a plural issue in the custom view title character validation.
The title is allowing 32 characters, if I'm trying to enter the 33rd character it showing the validation message as "Title is 1 character**s** too long." It is supposed to be "Title is 1 character too long."

> [image: Edit custom view]

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build.  Plurals a managed by our translation system and I forgot to add the English-language definition for the one case.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The new custom view title is allowing 32 characters length. If we are utilizing the full length in the title, the **Filter** and **Sort** are displaying the next line.

With less number of characters in title:

> [image: Less length title]

With 32 characters in title:

> [image: 32 char title]

The same design issue happened, when less number of characters title with **Sort: Bounty ending soon** option selected.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When I am viewing a custom question list, I am getting a notification saying

> X questions with new activity

But when I click on the notification, it shows questions that don't match my filters. Shouldn't new questions match my filters? Or at least don't show notifications at all.

I experienced this at the following URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers,Bounty&edited=true

I updated the filter to check for questions tagged PHP and I checked the "Has bounty" checkbox. But new questions are showing up without bounties.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @BrianNickel  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers,Bounty&edited=true. I have php tag with "Has Bounty" checked. New php questions show up but they don't have bounties.

Comment: I have a fix for this in code review.  Basically we weren't exposing enough information for the page to apply filters to the new questions.

Comment: This is fixed now.  The realtime banner is aware of those filters and is capable of handling things like `php -phpmyadmin` and `php or javascript ajax`

Comment: @BrianNickel Hey, it looks like this is not working, maybe it broke since it was fixed. And just to be clear, the issue is that my filter is for questions with bounties, but questions without bounties are popping up. Should I make a separate post with the bug details?

Answer (score 0):

[design](/questions/tagged/design)

While scrolling the page when the top bar is sticky, the opened custom view dialog box is overlapped with the top bar.

Since the other options, Filter, Sort are hide under the top bar while scrolling, for the uniformity the custom view dialog box also may hide under the top bar.

> [image: Custom view]

GIF for the same:

> [image: Custom view - GIF]

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the **Filter** option, if I select any tag with the **The following tags** option textbox and click out of the dialog box it closed the dialog box and the selected tag's related questions are loaded properly.

Again if I want to filter any other specific tag, I click on the **Reset** option which is located above the textbox and select any other tag, and clicked out of the dialog box, the newly selected tag's related questions are not loaded, instead it stayed with the previous selected tag. Seems in the second time the call is not triggered.

GIF for the same:

> [image: Reset and select tag]

Comment: This has been fixed.  There's some logic in place so it doesn't navigate every time the filter closes.  Despite having written comparison the methods myself, I was calling them the wrong way and comparing the wrong things.