# Make favorite tags to show on the left bar

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, left-nav

It would be nice to have your favorite/watched tags to show up on the left column. This way I can quickly go to the tags of interest when I visit a site.

Answer (score 3):

You can add lists (and not just of your favorite tags) to the right sidebar (of the questions tab) by adding filters:

[image: a list of my filters; underneath is “create a custom filter”]

Comment: How do I create a Custom View?

Comment: @Kousha You need to [opt  into](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/323179) CQL and then it’s under “[more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323202/323179)”.