# Add a "Watched Tags" tab to the "Top Questions" on the Home page

Tags: feature-request, questions, tag-watching

**Background:**

Watched Tags represents the tags/questions that the user is interested in or could answer. However, the current use-case for Watched Tags seems to be to click each tag in the Watched Tags panel on the Home page individually to find questions related to these tags.

i.e. If I watch 5 tags, I would need to click each of the 5 links in turn.

**Proposed improvement:**

Top Questions on the Home page has tabs for Interesting, Featured, Hot, etc. I propose adding Watched Tags to the list. I imagine this as a single place where a user could see all questions related to the tags they're watching.

i.e. This view would be one list of questions related to any of the 5 tags I'm following.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new [Custom Question Lists functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317675/295232) already does this, though it's a few more clicks. It's currently in beta testing and you need to [opt in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/custom-question-lists-is-available-for-testing) first.

By default, it contains a view with all unanswered questions in your watched tags:

[image]

If instead you want to see *all* questions, you can create a new custom view with the + button and select 'My watched tags':

[image]

It's then available for you from the /questions page:

[image]

Comment: This feature is in beta testing. For instructions on how to opt-in, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/custom-question-lists-is-available-for-testing.

Comment: Oops, forgot that it wasn't live for everyone *automatically*. Thanks!

Comment: IMO it's also 50/50 chance of ever being live, since SE will always have more urgent things to do. So at some point, it might get buried like the previous "new nav". That's why I don't bother to test it: 50% of total waste of my time.

Comment: ... and we just got a [new update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327816/295232) about that topic :)

Comment: Yeah, I submitted a request to get access to the beta 6 days ago and I still can't access the beta. :-/