# Should we remind users with a link to their question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits, accepted-answer

**What this question is about:**

It occurred to me that even experienced users occasionally forget that they either:

1. received viable answers to existing questions or
2. need to edit existing questions to get more appropriate answers.

**What this question is not about:**

1. I'm not suggesting that we badger "or otherwise nudge" users into accepting answers to their questions, as per this discussion: [Comments saying "thank you" remind OP to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177292/comments-saying-thank-you-remind-op-to-accept-answer)
2. I'm not duplicating the discussions about reminding/educating new users to accept answers to their questions, as discussed here: [Remind new users to choose some answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers) and elsewhere.

**My personal rationale:**

I suspect that OPs occasionally hesitate to accept an answer in hope that someone will later post a better answer even though there may already be acceptable answers provided. I know that I have done this in the past and then forgotten about my question, only to remember months or years later that I hadn't yet accepted a viable answer to my question.

For busy people, it's inconvenient to go through your activity history and find the question with the upvoted answer that still was never accepted. The inconvenience factor is enough of a deterrent that busy people don't always do it.

**My proposal:**

For a question with unaccepted answers for over a year, could we please alert the OP ***with a link*** (this is the key feature) to their question with a suggestion to perhaps review their question to edit it if no acceptable answers have been provided (or something like that)?

Perhaps there could be other criteria to prevent obnoxious reminders, such as the question needing to have at least 3 suggested answers or that the suggested answers must have been upvoted at least 3 times or that the question has been upvoted at least once or something like that.

Comment: I am unable to recall but this thing happens in some way. I don't know how but I having a feeling that community user notify us in some way but I am not sure about it.

Comment: This is a good idea but I'm afraid it might not get much traction. People are just too stoic towards accepts. I can confirm it has happened often enough to me though, that I meant to accept an answer but waited a while not to close the case too soon, and forgot it. (I can think of a potential downside when people would just see this as an annoyance, especially more common askers)

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar I think you're referring to the banner that's shown as soon as you upvote an answer, as the OP of a question. That's quite different from what this feature request is about.

Comment: @Glorfindel, that question was about assigning reputation, not about giving a reminder link.

Comment: The question discusses a potential reminder for accepting an answer on unaccepted questions. The answers tell **why we shouldn't push users into accepting an answer.** It's simply not that important, at least not as important as a high score by the community. I'd rather have a user not accepting an answer than accepting an answer which the community deems to be suboptimal (or even bad).

Comment: @Glorfindel, it wouldn't push users into accepting an answer if it's a setting that could be turned on that's disabled by default. I know that I personally would like to get a link like that because I don't have time to track down old posts.

Comment: Agree it is not a duplicate. In the very least, it deserves more users to decide such a thing, so I've reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notifications probably aren't going to fly (it's *ok* to not accept an answer), but there's a workaround for the problem you described.

> For busy people, it's inconvenient to go through your activity history and find the question with the upvoted answer that still was never accepted. The inconvenience factor is enough of a deterrent that busy people don't always do it.

If the motivation for your question is to make it easier to review/address these cases, I have good news for you: you can use search to find these.  Search for: `user:me is:q answers:1 hasaccepted:no` (replace "answers:1" with whatever threshold you like).  You can use `created:..YYYY-MM-DD` to restrict the search to questions asked before a certain date.  See the [search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for more options.

This search returns all of your questions have have answers and no accepted answer.  Unfortunately, on-site search doesn't let you filter *question* searches by *answer score*, but you could use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) to write a SQL query to find those.

Eventually you might be able to use [custom question filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317675/custom-question-lists-october-status-update) to find these.  That still won't push out notifications, but it'd be more visible than search or a SEDE query.